# Copy files with partial resume support? (Win/Cygwin)

Tags: windows, cygwin, file-transfer

Just curious if anyone knows of a tool that'll copy files, and should the file get interrupted, have it resume where it's left off the next time it's invoked.

I'm basically trying to copy something over samba using an unreliable WiFi connection.  Ideally I'd like something like wget or axel that works over samba/file system.  Cygwin or Windows solutions would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rsync` will do this for you, over a samba share or over SSH.  See [`man rsync`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/) on your system for the gory details.  `rsync` is available as a Cygwin package.

Use `-P` or `--partial` for resuming an interrupted transfer.

There are lots of rsync questions already on this site; see https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rsync for examples of how others are using it.

Comment: This is a good way to go since you already have Cygwin.

Comment: Neat.  I didn't know rsync had a partial command.  Good catch.

Comment: ROBOCOPY or XCOPY with flag /Z should work too. See ROBOCOPY /? or XCOPY /? for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think RoboCopy is ideal for this situation. RoboCopy is mostly used when backing up an active partition that has the OS on it. It is able to copy files that are locked and in use, therefore creating a complete backup even while the OS is being used. Take a look at [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php), not only will it help you here but you might be pleasantly surprised at the speed increase and greater reliability on local Windows transfers.

Comment: I like TeraCopy in general. It does pause and let you resume, when it finds the target disk going full for example. But, I don't think it can handle a restart of the copy if the copy instance window is closed (with a skip). So, I can't easily complete the copy 'tomorrow' for example.

Answer (score -1):

Hrmm, just found [RoboCopy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displayLang=en). Might be worth looking into!